# Below code is not working, when I try to display textbox values in another view. I'm getting default values only. I'm using mvc5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Below is my view code. customer class object returning from this is null.I'm a beginner in mvc.

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Customer
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>InputCustomerWithHelper</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        @using(Html.BeginForm("DisplayCustomerWith","First",FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <p>Customer Name    @Html.TextBoxFor(n=>n.customerName)</p>
            <p>Customer ID   @Html.TextBoxFor(n=>n.customerId)</p>
            <p> Amount to be Paid  @Html.TextBoxFor(n=>n.amount)</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Adding controller code,model code and view code for display value from textbox.

### Model code

```
public class Customer
{
    public string customerName;
    public int customerId;
    public decimal amount;
}
```

Code for textbox value display

```
<div> 
    Customer Name : @Model.customerName
    Customer ID : @Model.customerId
    Amount : @Model.amount
</div>
```

Controller code

```
public ActionResult InputCustomerWithHelper()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisplayCustomerWith(Customer obj)
{
    return View("LoadCustomerData",obj);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _returning from this is null_? `null` where? In the POST method? In the view? Show the relevant code (the model and the controller methods)

Comment: @Stephen: I have added the code. When I debugged I could see null value in customer obj(in controller code).

Comment: Your `Customer` is NOT `null` - its the values of its fields that are `null`! The `DefaultModelBinder` does not bind fields, only properties. Make them all properties - `public string customerName { get; set; }` and it will work fine

Comment: Its working. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your action with same model :

```
//Action should be POST method "DisplayCustomerWith" and Controller will be "First" with "Customer" model
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisplayCustomerWith(Customer objCustomer)
{
return view();
}

Hope this will help you !!!
```